# Making remote database backup into local folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I call this T-SQL script against a remote SQL Server database from a batch file in my local machine:

`MyBatchFile.bat`:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" 
      -S RemoteIPaddress -U username -P userPassword -i D:\MyBackups\backup_db.sql
```

`backup_db.sql`:

```
declare @backupfile nvarchar(255)

set @backupfile = N'D:\MyLocalBackups\' +
                  CONVERT(varchar(4), datepart(yy, getdate())) +
                  right('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), datepart(mm, getdate())),2) +
                  right('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), datepart(dd, getdate())),2) +
                  N'_' +
                  right('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), datepart(hour, getdate())),2) +
                  right('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), datepart(minute, getdate())),2) +
                  N'_MyDbBackup.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = @backupfile
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'MyDatabase Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10

GO
```

And I want the backup to be placed into my local machine from where I execute it but it seems it is trying to do the backup and place it into the remote machine instead so I get below error:

> Cannot open backup device 'D:\MyLocalBackups\20131011_1200_MyDbBackup.bak'. Operating system error 21(The device is not ready.).

How can I do this?

Note that `.bat` file and `.sql` file are placed in my local machines, not in the remote.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do two things:

1. Share that folder on your box so it can be accessed with a UNC path like `\\MachineName\MyLocalBackups\20131011_1200_MyDbBackup.bak`.
2. Give `NETWORK SERVICE` full access to that folder.

Comment: That's assuming the remote server can get to the local box which isn't always the case with network and firewall rules.

Comment: @acfrancis, yeah I probably should have mentioned that. I just kind of assumed that general network access issues apply to this approach.

Comment: I tend to assume the opposite: the database is locked away and only accessible from specific locations. If that's the case, you just need to turn your solution upside down: Backup to a folder on the remote server and copy it over the UNC path. That's also more reliable as the backup process isn't dependent on the network.

Comment: May be SQL Server does not have rights for this local path? You can check this in SSMS when try to make backup manually. If you see `'D:\MyLocalBackups\'` then you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **sp_addumpdevice**

```
EXEC sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'temp1', '\\MachineName\MyLocalBackups\20131011_1200_MyDbBackup.bak'
go

sqlcmd -S. -T -q BACKUP DATABASE [temp_database] TO  [temp1] WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'temp_database-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Useful:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/21ec66c2-955d-4c9f-a805-b96c93a240d2/how-to-backup-remote-ms-sql-server-database-to-local-disk-using-sqlcmd?forum=sqltools